# Convert input to text without affecting table columns

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working with HTML, PHP and JavaScript. I tried to create a form that can convert inputs into text. But the problem is that, when I click the button, all columns are affected.

This is my code for the input table:

```
<td>
  <form method="POST" name="f1" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>">
     <input type="text" name="amount" id="fileserver" placeholder="Please Enter Amount">
     <div id="test"></div>
     <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-1 text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="disable_all();">SUBMIT</button>
     </div>
   </form>
 </td>
```

And this is my JavaScript Code:

```
<script>
        function disable_all()
        {
        $( "form" ).html($( "#fileserver" ).val());
        }
</script>
```

When I try to input a value, all of the rows are affected. How to fix this kind of issue? How can I input a value without affecting other columns? I hope someone will try to fix this. Thank you.

**[FIDDLE FOR FULL REFERENCE](http://jsfiddle.net/rsa30qLw/7/)**

Comment: I'm confused, could you explain what this has to do with C?

Comment: Nah. wrong tag mate. My bad

Comment: which other columns are affected?